# APV PDF Viewer : How to build for Android NDK x86 Platform?

Tags: android, android-ndk, x86, arm, android-x86

APV PDF Viewer [Link](http://code.google.com/p/apv/)

is it possible to build this "APV PDF Viewer [[apv-0.3.3dev01.tar.gz]](http://code.google.com/p/apv/downloads/detail?name=apv-0.3.3dev01.tar.gz&can=2&q=)" code for Android NDK x86 Build ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here two file changes required :

[1] FILE : apv-0.3.3dev01.tar\pdfview\jni\Application.mk

```
    APP_MODULES := pdf fitz fitzdraw jpeg pdfview2 jbig2dec openjpeg
    APP_OPTIM := release
    APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi
        Change to APP_ABI := x86
```

[2] FILE : apv-0.3.3dev01.tar\pdfview\jni\mupdf\draw\Android.mk

```
    LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3 -DARCH_ARM
        Change to  LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3   [  remove " -DARCH_ARM " ]
```

Comments :

"-DARCH_ARM" option is for ARM processor power optimization.

- Under this option code will try to use special optimized instructions for ARM Architecture, Those Instructions are not available for x86 processor instruction sets ]